sum of Σ 1/(n*n!)
I was trying to solve a series using partial fractions and this series popped up and I am confused that even if it is solvable. Is this series solvable by using basic techniques of partial fractions or telescoping???

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: assuming your series starts at $n=1$, use $\frac1n=\int_0^1x^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x$ to get an integral, then use these.
